# OnTouch MotionEvent Action Move not triggering

Tags: java, android, android-activity, touch, draggable

I'm trying to get X, Y coordinates while I'm dragging my button, but for some reason, the code bellow attached on touch listener triggers only twice instead of constant update while dragging, even with trothing I will be satisfied in order to improve performance, but as I said, `onTouch` method triggered just on action down, and one more time later.

This is my code:

```
final Button dragBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyTestButton);

    dragBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(dragBtn);
        v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
        int action = me.getAction();


        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            Log.i("TEST", "ACTION_DOWN");
            return true;
        }


        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            Log.i("TEST", "ACTION_MOVE");

            float x = me.getX();
            float y = me.getY();

            //TODO: Rest of my code here.

            return true;
        }

        if (action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

            Log.i("TEST", "ACTION_UP");
            return true;
        }

        Log.i("TEST", "UKNOWN ACTION");
        return true;
    }
});
```

And in log I have just:

```
ACTION_DOWN
WindowManager﹕ Drag already in progress
UKNOWN ACTION
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to capture the X and Y coordinate data in your `OnDragListener` not your `OnTouchListener`. For the whole time that you are dragging the object around the screen, Android interprets that as one single ACTION_MOVE event, hence you only get data once from that. Place the following code inside your custom `OnDragListener` class:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    float xCoord;
    float yCoord;
    if(action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION) {
        xCoord = event.getX();
        yCoord = event.getY();
    }
    return event.getResult();       //returns true for valid drop or false for invalid drop
}
```

Somewhere else in your custom `OnDragListener` class, you will have to do something with that xCoord and yCoord data. For example in my app, I have a `TextView` on my "debug" version of the app where I display the xCoord and yCoord data. I execute the `TextView.setText()` method right after I get those two values in my `if(action == DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION){...` section.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried that also, but the issue there is that event fires randomly sometimes like 3 or 4 times, sometimes 6, 7 and stop, even if I continue to drag object. However I didn't try with ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION I tried just with DRAG_ENTER. I will try that soon.

Comment: @ShP I recommend putting `event.getX()` and `event.getY()` only in ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION so you don't get duplicate data. You should be aware that even if you start dragging the object and then hold your finger still (before dropping the object), Android will probably still register some movement because of touch slop associated with just touching the screen. You can probably reduce some of that "noise" by truncating the Float values (or casting them to Integer) returned by `event.getX()` and `event.getY()`.

Comment: Hm, it looks like your code works, BUT, does not solve my issue. The thing is, in theory this SHOULD work, but, it does not work, because after few moves I start getting "Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed", which is ridicules, and my thread is dropped. Any solution for that? I'm getting that with your code above.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't run into that problem that you just described so I'm not entirely sure how to help there. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

MotionEvent.getAction encodes the action type as well as additional pointer information (for multi-touch handling).  You want [MotionEvent.getActionMasked](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getActionMasked()) to get just the action part.

Edit: also, per discussion below there's some issue with startDragging.

Comment: Hi @Darrell, but I don't understand how this will help. Even if I change the motion getAction to getActionMasked, that won't solve the problem since this method onTouch is triggered only twice. I change for example to log masked action, but same thing, just two log details, one with value 0, and after that with 3. Put the code above in some activity and attach it to some dummy button and you will see the same results.

Comment: Gotcha, you should continue to see events so long as you return true from onTouch.  Try moving the startDrag inside your ACTION_DOWN clause, maybe second call with the "drag already in progress" error is causing the system to abort the drag?

Comment: Hey @Darrell, thanks! That was the problem! You can edit your answer, but I will accept it anyway. That damn piece of code was causing the trouble, when I removed that, it fires as expected. However, if I put that code under action down, same error. Any solution for that?

Comment: Interesting -- I've not used startDrag before but it sounds like you might to do a little more to use the "drag and drop" framework.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

Answer (score 1):

Once the system has the drag shadow, it begins the drag and drop operation by sending drag events to all the View objects in your application that are currently visible. It does this either by calling the View object's drag listener (an implementation of onDrag() or by calling the View object's onDragEvent() method. Both are passed a DragEvent object that has a getAction() value of ACTION_DRAG_STARTED

Answer (score 0):

finaly your code should be like this.

```
int basex;
int basey;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
RelativeLayout layBg;


....................

dragBtn.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) dragBtn.getLayoutParams();

        switch (me.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        basex = ((int) (me.getRawX() - layoutParams.leftMargin));
                        basey = ((int) (me.getRawY() - layoutParams.topMargin));
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        int i = (int) event.getRawX();
                        int j = (int) event.getRawY();
                        layBg = ((RelativeLayout) dragBtn.getParent());
                        if ((i - basex > -(dragBtn.getWidth() * 2 / 3))
                                && (i - basex < layBg.getWidth() - dragBtn.getWidth() / 3)) {
                            layoutParams.leftMargin = (i - basex);
                        }
                        if ((j - basey > -(dragBtn.getHeight() * 2 / 3))
                                && (j - basey < layBg.getHeight() - dragBtn.getHeight() / 3)) {
                            layoutParams.topMargin = (j - basey);
                        }
                        layoutParams.rightMargin = -1000;
                        layoutParams.bottomMargin = -1000;
                        dragBtn.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        break;

                    }

                    return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi, I will test this soon. One question doe, will this move entire button, or create a "copy" of button since I don't want to ended up with empty place from where I start dragging a button.

Comment: the code is just for move entire button,
not to create copy.

Comment: Hey @Ravi, this is not good nor working solution, this just update margins and messes up rest of the UI. I need working solution with this `View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(dragBtn);`

Comment: ok NP,
it is working at my place,
I don't know to implement DragShadowBuilder.