# Action Bar - Drag Menu Item

Tags: java, android, android-layout, draggable

How can I setOnTouchListener to action bar menu item in order to add functionality to drag some item from action bar?

For example, if I do this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <item android:id="@+id/my_menu_item_button"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
            android:title="TEST"
            app:showAsAction="always"  />

</menu>
```

And try to do this:

```
final MenuItem myMenuItem = (MenuItem) findViewById(R.id.action_search);

myMenuItem.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {             
        return true;
    }
});
```

I can't because setOnTouchListener needs view.

Any solution for this?

Here's the skeleton:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b654b67d4dbd45ce8539

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
View you can find easily by using menuItem.getActionView(), but I guess you get the action view as null if you have not set any custom view using MenuItem.setActionView().

Solution : 
Lets create a layout file called sample_action_view.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mobile_link_action_bar_button" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:src="sampleImage.png"
        android:contentDescription="Sample Image"/>    
</LinearLayout>


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService
                (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View sampleActionView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_action_view, null);
        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_myDemoToolbarButton);
        serachMenuItem.setActionView(sampleActionView);

        sampleActionView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: can you please provide example for this? You ware right for null, I'm getting: "Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View android.view.MenuItem.getActionView()' on a null object reference".

Comment: View sampleView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sampleLayout, null);myMenuItem.setActionView(sampleView), put all your listener over sampleView.

Comment: what is this "inflater", I don't have that in code, getLayoutInflater()?

Comment: I managed to use different view for my button, and now my button is rendered from that view, but I can't make this setOnTouchListener to work. No matter if I try to attach it inside the onCreateOptionsMenu or in my main activity, it's not getting triggered...

Comment: LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)<Activity/Context>.getApplicationContext().getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); I didn't try for setOnTouchListener, but definitely setOnClickListener work for me !

Comment: Can you please provide full valid gist so that I can compare where did you put this entire code, in onCreateOptionsMenu or in onCreate for activity... along with that listener.

Comment: Please check the edited answer. Hopefully this will give you some help.

Comment: Hey Dex, I tried with code above, but I didn't get any results.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b654b67d4dbd45ce8539 I removed all from onCreateOptionsMenu since it's not working

Comment: Hey ShP, Hopefully now you find some help, posted the solution here as well in github that worked for me !

Comment: Thank you :) I managed to apply this yesterday but forget to say thanks. Btw, here's another issue related to dragging if you know solution you may get bounty again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667910/ontouch-motionevent-action-move-not-triggering